# mergeMap service in rxjs 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I am trying to upgrade my project based on some template from angular 5 to 6

one of the method return mergeMap in this way

```
return this.accountEndpoint.getUserByUserNameEndpoint<User>(userOrUserId.userName)
                    .mergeMap(user => this.deleteUser(user.id));
```

and some other in this way return

```
 this.accountEndpoint.getDeleteUserEndpoint<User>(<string>userOrUserId)
                 .do(data => this.onRolesUserCountChanged(data.roles));
```

unfortunately mergeMap and do does not exists on observable in rxjs 6

Couuld give me a hint how should this be mapped in new worlds of rxjs 6 ?

Comment: check here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md :). "do" operator have been renamed to "tap", i dont know about mergeMap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `do` operator was renamed to [tap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap), but [mergeMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap) still exists in RxJs 6:

```
import { tap, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators'

sourceObservable.pipe(
  tap(e => ...),
  mergeMap(e => ...)
)
```